# How to update a mysql database without reloading page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

thanks for looking. 
I have a very long list of items, users click on an image (a plus sign) to add the item to their personal list. At the moment when they click the + it loads a "add-item.php?itemid=*" which processes the below code then redirects them to their own list, I did have it redirecting back to the global list but then it was unclear to the user if the item was added to their list. how would I go about making it all update the database without going anywhere, im thinking javascript but have never written any. Any help would be brilliant!! :)

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

 $bucketlist=MYSQL_QUERY( "SELECT * FROM membersbuckets where userid = $userid AND bucketid = $bucketid")
 or die(mysql_error());  

          $bucketlist=mysql_fetch_array( $bucketlist ) ;

            if($bucketlist < 1) {

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO membersbuckets (memberbucketid, userid, bucketid, complete)
            VALUES ('', '$userid', '$bucketid', '0')");
            echo "Adding item to your bucketlist...";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='2; URL=mybucketlist.php'/>";
            }
            else {
            echo "This item is already on your list, redirecting you to your list";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='2; URL=mybucketlist.php'/>";
            }
?>
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need AJAX, as everyone has said.

Since you have never written any javascript, here is a guide for you.

Instead of your

```
<a href="add-item.php?itemid='.$itemId.'" > Add Item </a>
```

Write

```
<a onclick="addItemToUsersList('.$itemId.')" > Add </a>
```

For AJAX, use jquery as Angelo has suggested. Download it and add the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://path/to/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javasript">
function addItemToUsersList(itemId)
{
  $.ajax({
    'url': 'path/to/add-item.php', 
    'type': 'GET',
    'dataType': 'json', 
    'data': {itemid: itemId}, 
    'success': function(data) 
    {
      if(data.status)
      {
        if(data.added)
        {
          $("span#success"+itemId).attr("innerHTML","Item added to your personal list");
        }
        else
        {
          $("span#success"+itemId).attr("innerHTML","This item is already on your list");
        }
      }
    },
    'beforeSend': function() 
    {
      $("span#success"+itemId).attr("innerHTML","Adding item to your bucketlist...");
    },
    'error': function(data) 
    {
      // this is what happens if the request fails.
      $("span#success"+itemId).attr("innerHTML","An error occureed");
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

And then finally, in your `path/to/add-item.php` file write the code to add the items. The parameter `itemId` will be available here as `$_GET['itemId']`. Just return proper status values using json_encode.

```
if($bucketlist < 1) 
{
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO membersbuckets (memberbucketid, userid, bucketid, complete) VALUES ('', '$userid', '$_GET['itemId]', '0')");
  return json_encode(array("status" => true, "added" => true));
}
else
{
  return json_encode(array("status" => true, "added" => false));
}
```

Comment: sandeepan, firstly thank you for such an indepth answer! 
I have downloaded (and uploaded) a copy of jquery... added a link to the jquery file and added the function script between the head tags. Added the click code:    
<a onclick='addItemToUsersList("<?php echo $itemid ; ?>")'> Add<img src='images/plus-green.png' /> </a>
Although the add link is link colour, and rollover changes colour like a propper <a> link it doesn't actually do anything... I have created a test page copy that I am playing with - http://olbl.co.uk/showbucketsTEST.php. Can you see what I have done wrong? 
Thank you!! :)

Comment: Thanks for my first best answer...
I checked your test page. It gives `302 Moved Temporarily` error. Go to the URL http://olbl.co.uk/member-bucketadd-execTEST.php?itemId=25 and see. It redirects to your login page. An AJAX processing file should not be login protected. Remove the redirection and it will work fine

Comment: A little correction here... the code can be login protected but remove the redirection. Return a json array instead and then display message like other cases

Answer (score 3):

You would achieve this via JavaScript utilizing something referred to as "AJAX". An Asynchronous JavaScript And XML request allows JavaScript to send a request to another page and get the results from it.

So utilizing ajax, you would go to the URL you wanted, and then you could display the message to a user.

I use a library called jQuery to get something like this done

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'path/to/add-item.php', 
    'type': 'GET',
    'dataType': 'json', 
    'data': {itemid: xx}, 
    'success': function(data) {
      // what happens if the request was completed properly
    },
    'error': function(data) {
      // what happens if the request fails.
    }
  });
```

Note that just because a request completes properly, doesn't mean the item was added as necessary.

I would suggest you read up on the following to get a good understanding of how exactly to adapt this to your needs.

http://json.org/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

https://www.php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 1):

http://jquery.com/ would be my suggestions. You are going to need to do some AJAX calls to the server to have it interact with your DB and then get a result back and display that information to the user. I prefer JQuery as it simplifies a lot of these calls and the documentation for it is fairly good. There are tons of tutorials around for the basics.

A simple google search reveals quite a few http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+ajax+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You may really want to use Javascript in your project! See, because you are telling that you dont want to navigate out of the current page and want to give a small message on the current page saying a confirmation to the user.. then u need to use something called as AJAX-Asynchronous Javascript and XML. Its a addition of PHP and Javascript.

Using AJAX u can update currently loaded page without refreshing it. Here HTML is not connecting or requesting the server but its the Javascript. Hence u can achieve -> [how would I go about making it all update the database without going anywhere]..

And as far AJAX and Javascript is concerned, they r very simple! Just need to learn basic syntax of them and den on u can go further!!!

references u can refer to:

-> Best book for u to refer is -

Professional Ajax
Nicholas C. Zakas, Jeremy McPeak, Joe Fawcett

Comment: Code blocks are not for quotes. Please use blockquote (`>`) instead.