# Cant get Ajax to work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have found this question wich i am trying to use to update my database without leaving the page.

[How to update a mysql database without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630042/how-to-update-a-mysql-database-without-reloading-page)

I am trying to create the script posted by Sandeepan Nath.

What i have is a litle bit edited.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addItemToUsersList(itemId)
{
  $.ajax
  ({
  'url': 'addtofavourit.php', 
   'type': 'GET',
  'dataType': 'json', 
  'data': {itemid: itemId}, 
   'success': function(data) 
   {
       if(data.status)
       {
           if(data.added)
            {
                   alert("Item added to your personal list");
             }
             else
             {
                    alert("This item is already on your list");
            }
        }
   },
   'beforeSend': function() 
     {
           alert("Adding item to your bucketlist...");
     },
      'error': function(data) 
      {
        // this is what happens if the request fails.
        alert("An error occureed");
    }
});
```

}

and my html (created out of a loop from php)

```
<div style="margin-top:40px;">
      <a onclick="addItemToUsersList(<?php echo $imgid ?>)" ><b>Add to favourit</b
</a>
</div>
```

And finally the content of addtofavourit.php wich is in the same folder as the page im trying to run the ajax from.

```
<?php
if($_GET['itemId'] > 1) //just for debugging should always atleast return status true..
 {
    return json_encode(array("status" => true, "added" => true));
 }
 else
 {
    return json_encode(array("status" => true, "added" => false));
 }
?>
```

The result of this is that i first get an alert box as expected with "  Adding item to your bucketlist...  "

but after that message i get a new alert box with:

An error occureed

What can be wrong i tryd to change addtofavourit.php to 
http://www.domain.com/pathto/addtofavourit.php  (WHERE http://www.domaim.com/pathto/ is my personal website just added for the example. ) and to ../addtofavourit.php  but it didn't help.

Can some one plz help me because i dont know were to look.

Comment: Check your console for errors? Also, this seems like a `POST` request.

Comment: The link given is not working ... can you check it or try to show the error message.

Comment: the link i guess you mean http://www.domain.com/pathto/addtofavourit.php is an example domain.com is changed with my real domain

Comment: @tymeJV  Post And get can be changed later get should work i guess..

Comment: Shouldn't you be echoing in php rather than returning?

Comment: I dont know much about json thats why i coppied the accepted answer and tryd to edit it.

Comment: THX it was indeed echo instead of return if you post that as an answer i will except it. Dont get why the question(link i posted) accepted the answer though

Answer (score 0):

Might the page to which you are sending ajax request in not in place (there might be problem with proper path), **try analyzing it with firebug** and if you see that the ajax request has turned **red** in color that something is wrong with your request !

Comment: Not turning red its all black

Answer (score -1):

First add the ContentType before the data type:

(sometimes this causes the async call does not work very well)
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

And also remove the singles quotes in all the parameters (url,type, success,etc)

Comment: i see you use double quotes arround "application/json; charset=utf-8",  i have single quotes ' should i change everything to double quotes? And do i need to remove the quotes arround success before send etc to?

Comment: I think this is the same (it only an usage), but yes try to use double quotes and also add the ContentType.

Comment: and yes remove the quotes arround succes, url and all the parameters

Comment: Tryd all the above but didnt do it. also added alert(data); to error: but it gives back Object.object

Comment: try to return only a simple string  in the call and maybe this is the error (on the server side)

Comment: contentType application/json is invalid for this request, he's not sending json to the server. The quotes around object keys are irrelevant. If he returns just a string the ajax is going to fail with a parseerror.